# How to fix vsce not packaging code changes into .vsix file

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vsix

I'm developing an extension in vscode, and using [vsce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vsce) to package it into a .vsix file. 
I noticed a typo in my description in my extension's package.json, noticeable when the extension is installed and loaded in the extension tab. So I fixed it and re-ran `vsce package` in ~/extension_name/client/ and re-installed the extension, but the typo remains.

I've double checked I'm not installing the wrong .vsix file. I've ran `npm install` in ~/extension_name/client/. I've even committed my changes to a branch in git, downloaded that branch and packaged it, no luck.

**Do I need to run another command to get vsce to realise there are changes to include? How can I determine what version of the code vsce is packaging up?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same issue in the past, where I repackaged an extension with the same version and it didn't get installed properly.

VSCode installs extensions to `~/.vscode/extensions`, so you can inspect the code in your extension's directory there. I think VSCode is just failing to overwrite the existing extension there, so try deleting the extension within that folder and then installing the .vsix again.

To see the contents of the `.vsix` file, you can change the file extension to `.zip`. (See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/quanto/2009/05/26/what-is-a-vsix/)
For VSCode extensions, there should be an 'extension' folder inside it which has all of your code.

Comment: Thanks for answering :) I don't have a ~/.vscode/extensions folder! Is yours always visible?

Comment: Hmm, yeah it is. Are you using insiders? If so, then it's ~/.vscode-insiders/extensions. docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_where-are-extensions-installed

Comment: Or rather, it's not visible by default in Finder because it starts with '.', but I have no problem navigating to it from the terminal

Comment: you're right, my bad. I was looking in the ~/extension_name/client/.vscode directory